# OPENCART -> Multi-store: how to edit .tpl files for each store?

Tags: opencart, multistore

I have an opencart based store and now I need to clone it to for an special offer my company will do in the next days.

The clone will be, as the name says, an exact copy of the current store, same layout, database and etc. The fact is, the duplicate need some adjustments on layout such as different banners, buttons that should appear only on the main store, some color changes on certain elements. In short words, I need to edit the .tpl files for this duplicate version, but keeping intact the mmain store's original look, how can I do it?

Thanks a lot fellas!

Comment: Please be specific in your question.  Do you not know how to edit text files?  Access the files?  Copy the files?

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm using Openchart with vQmod for some months, but its the first time I'm using the multi-store feature and I'm unsure how to make store-specific modifications. I thought about cloning the whole template folder to "create" an secondary template to use on the cloned store. But it doesn't seem elegant enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as cloning the default template directory and then assigning that template clone to your new store. Edit whatever files you need in this clone template and the changes will only apply to your new store and your original store will stay intact as it uses it's own template theme.